# How can I make my ActionBar's "Up" button work like the phone's "Back" button?

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I have a `ViewPager` with `Fragment`s. When a button is clicked in the `Fragment`, I launch an `Activity` on mine. Pressing the back button on my phone when I'm in the `Activity`, takes me back to my previous screen i.e. the one with the `Fragment`s in the `ViewPager`.

I'd like to enable the "up" button in my `ActionBar` and in order to do so, I've written the following code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.detail);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

Now the "up" button is shown, but clicking it doesn't take me back to the previous screen. I'd like the "up" button to the same thing as the "back" button.

How can I do this? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't use the up button as a back button. The aim of the Up button is to go up and not back. You should consider using it as it should. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Up

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You need also to implement what should be done when the up button is clicked:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { 
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home: 
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: This is the issue I had.  I was expecting the button to be automatically wired up, but when clicked, nothing happened.  After overriding onOptionItemSelected() with the code above, it worked like a champ.  Thanks!